# Is there a way to determine where specific Quartermaster Depot companies were based in WWII?

Tags: sources, world-war-two, resource

My father-in-law was a master sergeant of a Quartermaster Corps Depot Company during the Battle of the Bulge.  I would like to find out where his depot was located (and I'm assuming it moved from time to time), and to find out which armies, divisions and battalions it was assigned to equip.  How can I find that information?

Comment: Would it be better to ask simply where X quartermaster depot was located during the war?